# Why did Rick not want to go with Aaron?

Tags: the-walking-dead

I watched [*The Distance* (S05E11)](http://walkingdead.wikia.com/wiki/The_Distance) but I just don't understand why didn't he want to go somewhere where he might get to stay instead of worrying Judith would attract the zombies?

Comment: Which episode did you just watch?

Comment: @HDE226868 They're referring to S05E11 - *The Distance*.

Comment: Well, have you watched the rest of the series? If so, you'd know by now the survivors, and Rick in particular, are wary of seemingly benevolent strangers offering shelter. See: Terminus, Woodbury, etc.

Comment: Remember when Terminus seemed like a good idea?

Answer (score 8):

Ideally, Rick *did* want to go with Aaron - but theirs is not an ideal world. Past experiences have taught Rick and the group to not trust strangers - especially ones who belong to groups - even those promising sanctuary. Consider the major groups that they've come in contact with thus far in the show:

- the nursing home group in Atlanta: not terrible, but they were ready to kill members of Rick's group.
- the Greene family: this worked out ok.
- The prisoners:  betrayed and tried to kill them
- Woodbury & the Governor: destroyed the prison, killed Herschel, Axel, responsible for the death of Andrea, tried to kill Glenn. The governor killed many of his own people.
- Tyrese, Sasha, et al: this turned out ok.
- Abraham, Eugene, Rosalita: this has turned out ok aside from Eugene lying to everyone about DC
- Terminus/The Hunters: Killed Bob, wanted to kill/eat the group.
- The Claimers: tried to rape Carl, wanted to kill Rick
- The Hospital Cops: kidnapped & killed Beth

Rick and the group would love to believe that Aaron would take them to a safe zone, but they're wary of anything strangers tell them, and will naturally distrust newcomers until they have proven themselves.